# Why is my KML data appearing all in one line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, kml

I have a KML file of Dutch national statistics which is a series of multiple layered KML files that I need to extract. I know exactly what I am looking for and what I need to extract, but why does my data of 161,903 in length just appear on on continuous line? As you can imagine, its a pain to deal with data in such a way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As KML file is just a XML, you need to use the **XML-Plugin**: Plugins -> XML Tools -> Pretty Print (libXML) or (XML only - with line breaks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>)

If you miss it, download it over **Plugin Manager**:

[image]

Comment: I downloaded XML Tools and followed your instructions. But unfortunately this didn't resolve my issue. The data isn't actually displayed, despite there being '-' menu options to open and hide a menu.

Comment: You need to select the line (from begin to the end) and click "Pretty Print (libXML) " - that works!